# Error sending message with FB API

Tags: javascript, fbconnect

I am doing something for a client and I wanted to test what I had so far by sending a message to the default test user. But it gave an error after I tried here it the function that isnt working...

```
function sendWithoutTimerFunc()
{   
    try
    {
        FB.ui({
            app_id: '1226220854077249',
            method: 'send',
            link: 'https://developers.facebook.com/apps/1226220854077249/roles/test-users/',
            to: '111526025937966',
            message: 'Hello test user',
            data: '...'
        });
    }
    catch(error)
    {
        alert(error); //Will change to console.log() later
    }
}
```

**Error**

```
This dialog has been passed a bad parameter.

API Error Code: 100
API Error Description: Invalid parameter
Error Message: Viewer cannot message specified recipients.
```

Comment: I got that id from my test user that came with the application thank you for letting me know. Ill add my profile as a test user and use that instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

id [111526025937966](http://facebook.com/111526025937966) is not a valid facebook id.

you should use a valid id. i'm not sure but you may able to use your own id too.

Comment: Added a test user but I could not send a message.

Comment: @user6031759 and what is the error you got?make sure you have authorize your app.you can send msg to only people who already Authorize your app